# Input function for multiple values in python

Tags: python, input, split

```
a,b=int(input("Enter two numbers").split())

print(a+b)
```

I have written this code to add two numbers while taking input using input() function.
It is giving an error.
I know we can convert to int using map function but how about this method?
What is the error here?
[The pic depicts th error which it gives]

Comment: This is the error---Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/1948728/Desktop/python/input_two_numbers.py", line 1, in <module>
    a,b=int(input("Enter two numbers").split())
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'list'

Comment: The error is that you're trying to convert *a list* to an int. That's why you need `map`.

Answer (score 0):

`split` returns a list of strings, so you need to call `int` on each of the items in that list. It doesn't make sense to call `int` on a list. For example

```py
>>> a, b = [int(x) for x in "1 2".split()]
>>> a
1
>>> b
2
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this (Using [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) function).

```py
a,b=map(int, input("Enter two numbers").split())

print(a+b)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x, y = input("Enter two values: ").split()

print(int(x)+int(y))
```